# Update Table Values while Incrementing the main value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables and I want to update current rows from that table to the main table, I am a DBA so for me I will end up writing a big loop so was thinking if any one can help me out. So basically I want to update Table 2 from Table 1 values of (latestTimestamp and count) and the catch is Table 2 count should get incremented from table 1 latest count such if Table 2 count is 48 and the table 1 latest count is 1 it should add the 1 to 48 and the value in Table 2 should be 49 with latesttime stamp from table 1. I hope I make sense.

Below is the data

Table 1 (Table Name)

```
Column > DBName  Proc Name               CTimeStmp                Count   LatestTimeStmp       Calls

Data >
DB_US,  upGetSelfServiceHelp,   2011-02-10 11:37:22.490,      48,   2013-06-17 07:21:41.480,      0
DB_US,  upGetSelfServiceHelp,   2011-02-10 11:37:22.490,      1,    2013-06-17 14:18:33.997,      0
```

Table 2  (Table Name)

```
Column > DBName  Proc Name               CTimeStmp                Count   LatestTimeStmp       Calls

Data >
DB_US   upGetSelfServiceHelp    2011-02-10 11:37:22.490   48    2013-06-17 07:21:41.480   0
```

Comment: What is the primary key for each table?

Comment: There is no primary key on the table...

Comment: Okay. Just trying to understand your request better. Is the purpose of Table 1 a running log of all proc calls and Table 2 an aggregate showing latest timestamp and total number of calls?

Comment: Yes basically the requirement is to get the unused stored procs in a database and keep saving the execution count of the stored procs and at the month end developers will evaluate which 1 to delete.

Comment: Okay. Let's go a step further in clarifying. [CTimeStmp] is each time the proc is run. [Count] is...the number of times it's run for that timestamp? [LatestTimeStmp] seems self-explanatory. [Calls] is the sum of [Count]? Why are all columns in both tables? Shouldn't [LatestTimeStmp] and [Calls] just be in Table 2? And can [DBName] and [ProcName] be thought of as primary key for Table 2?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the sum of the Count and the max LatestTimeStmp from Table 1 into Table 2?

Comment: I insert the data from the DMV into a temp table with below Query.
SELECT 
DB_NAME() AS strDatabaseName,
ob.name AS 'SPName',
ob.Create_Date,
qs.execution_count AS 'Execution Count',
qs.creation_time 'CreationTime',
qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Second, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) AS 'Calls/Second'
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt
LEFT OUTER JOIN
sys.objects ob
ON qt.objectid = ob.object_id
WHERE qt.dbid = (
SELECT dbid
FROM sys.sysdatabases
WHERE name = 'DBAdmin')
AND OB.TYPE = 'P'
ORDER BY
qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count DESC

Comment: So table 2 should contain a sum of all the counts and the maximum timestamp for each dbname/proc name? `select dbname, procname, sum(count), max(LatestTimeStmp) from table1` Use this result to update table 2.

Comment: And this is the filter...

;WITH GetUnusedStoredProc AS
(
SELECT
    strDatabaseName,strStoredProcName,dtCreateDate,intExecutionCount,dtLastExecuteDate,intCallsPerSecond,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY strStoredProcName ORDER BY strStoredProcName) AS RowNumber
    FROM #Temp
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you what you need?

```
update [Table 2] set
    [LatestTimeStmp] = (select max([LatestTimeStmp]) from [Table 1] t1 where t1.DBName = t2.DBName and t1.ProcName = t2.ProcName),
    [Count] = (select sum([Count]) from [Table 1] t1 where t1.DBName = t2.DBName and t1.ProcName = t2.ProcName)
from
    [Table 2] t2
```

or if the duplication of the subquery rubs you wrong, this does the same:

```
update [Table 2] set
    LatestTimeStmp = t1.LatestTimeStmp,
    [Count] = t1.Count
from
    [Table 2] t2
    join (
        select
            DBName,
            ProcName,
            max(LatestTimeStmp) LatestTimeStmp,
            sum(Count) [Count]
        from
            [Table 1]
        group by
            DBName,
            ProcName
        ) t1 on t1.DBName = t2.DBName and t1.ProcName = t2.ProcName
```

Comment: Well Whatever JC gave I am 90% fine with it, what I really needed was not a sum from Table 1 but the latest value form Table 1 to be added (Incremented) to table 2 count value....anyway superb suggestions and I believe thats the reason Developers\Good coders always have high visibility and respect....

Comment: @user1948904 - yes it would - if it worked. :) update-set doesn't support grouping or aggregate functions except in a subquery.

Comment: @DreamszAlone - If the latest value from T1 is always added to the total in T2 then it should be functionally equivalent to a sum, shouldn't it?